# Out of sample extension for Isomap in Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

If I'm fitting the isomap class with a certain dataset, then I transform with a different one, does that mean that Sklearn is doing out-of-sample extension ?

I.e.

```
isomap=sklearn.manifold.isomap()
isomap.fit(X1)

isomap.transform(X2)
```